# Transfer media files from an Android device to an iOS device

Tags: iphone, data-transfer, android

Is there any software or app that can directly transfer media files (videos, images, audio) from an Android device to an iOS device (similar to AirDrop)?

Answer (score 1):

While there's no native way to transfer media files from Android device to iOS, you can install and use a 3rd party app called [Xender](http://www.xender.com) to do so.

Since iOS doesn't provide direct access to file(s) and filesystem (unlike Android), the media will be transferred via the app and the same needs to be installed on both the devices.

Comment: Odd that the app supports transferring apps. That (obviously) won't work between Android and iOS but one wonders what would happen if you transfer an App from one iPhone to another...

Comment: @SteveChambers Highly likely that the feature is Android to Android only.

Comment: @NimeshNeema What about iExplorer?  if you transfer from Android to computer then use iExplorer to transfer to ios.

Comment: @jmh OP is seeking for a way to transfer directly from an Android device to an iOS device.